# Passing set of Ids to StandardSetController of Visualforce page controller from lightning web component

Tags: visualforce, lightning-web-components, standardsetcontroller, navigationmixin.navigate

I have a requirement to invoke an existing VF page (displaying list of records using StandardSetController) from my lightning component. In my javascript, i have constructed the URL as suggested [here](https://community.skuid.com/skuid/topics/passing-selected-id-to-apex-class-using-standard-set-controller?topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bfilter_by%5D=all&topic-reply-list%5Bsettings%5D%5Bpage%5D=1#reply_20531756) but the VF is only displaying the record corresponding to 1st Id passed in the URL.

LWC JS code snippet:

```
var el = this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');
var selected = el.getSelectedRows();
var arrayOfIds = [];
for(let request of selected){
     arrayOfIdsIds.push(request.Id);
}

this[NavigationMixin.GenerateUrl](
{
type: 'standard__webPage',
attributes:
{
url: '/apex/VisualForcePage?ids='+ arrayOfIds.join('&ids=')
}
}).then(generatedUrl =>
{
window.open(generatedUrl);

});
```

URL generated when it navigates to VF page is

https://sample--devas.lightning.force.com/lightning/webpage/%2Fapex%2FVisualForcePage%3Fids%3Da1D3L0000000OE4UAM%26ids%3Da1D3L0000000DsRUAU

Is there something wrong with this url OR can someone suggest alternate approach to call the VF page and pass list of Ids from js?

Comment: Your code looks like it will create a query string like this: `ids=xxx&ids=xxx&ids=xxx`. I don't think that's what you want, because you are repeatedly using the same key with different values.

Comment: You need to post your VF page. Since it is custom, there is no guarantee that it is reading parameters in the way you're passing them

Comment: @nbrown Even I was not sure if that is the correct way but it was suggested in the blog i have mentioned in my post. It seems that´s how StandardSetController expects the set of Ids to be passed to it although It is not documented anywhere.

Comment: @SebastianKessel thanks, VF page & controller code is very simply it is currently invoked from a custom button on a standard list view. It displays the records selected by user on a standard list and and does further processing.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read the blog post link until now, but it does say that's how standard set controllers expect IDs. One difference I notice between the blog URL and yours is that the blog is using a classic URL. Lightning could be a differentiating factor. Please post your VisualForce and any extension controller code so we can help narrow it down further.

Comment: @AdnanS. I cannot guess at what your page might or might not be doing. Without that code I cannot even be sure my suggestions would work.